# How can I get a space to take up space?

Tags: html, fiddle

I need a paragraph with a space to take up space.

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/o70gaLny/) fiddle shows that a space renders just the same as nothing at all:

```html
<p class='p1'>1</p>
<p class='p1'>2</p>
<p class='p1'> </p>
<p class='p1'>4</p>
```

How can I achieve this effect?

Comment: keep in mind that it is also is considered invalid HTML to have multiple elements with the same `id`, you should use classes instead

Answer (score 2):

Use a [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space).

```html
<p class='p1'>1</p>
<p class='p1'>2</p>
<p class='p1'>&nbsp;</p>
<p class='p1'>4</p>
```

Comment: Will post as a sep question.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `height: 20px` to your id

https://jsfiddle.net/viethien/L2eoyxhn/

If you dont want to put height, the best way is adding `&nbsp;` in your tag

Another way, you can add :after for #p1

```
#p1:after {
    content: '\200b';
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/viethien/L2eoyxhn/7/

Comment: I don't want to have to manually match `height` to my `font-size`.

Comment: you can add   `padding-bottom: 7px;` in your css. @Hien

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this `<p id='p1'> </p>` is a good pattern, my solution is create many class with different space

```css
p {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.space-medium {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.space-low {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p id='p1' class="space-low">1</p>
<p id='p2' class="space-low">2</p>
<p id='p4' class="space-medium">4</p>
```